# Create array in bash with variables as array name

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I'm not sure if this has been answered, I've looked and haven't found anything that looks like what I'm trying to do. I also posted this to stackexchange (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189293/create-array-in-bash-with-variables-as-array-name)

I have a number of shell scripts that are capable of running against a ksh or bash shell, and they make use of arrays. I created a function named "setArray" that interrogates the running shell and determines what builtin to use to create the array - for ksh, set -A, for bash, typeset -a. However, I'm having some issues with the bash portion.

The function takes two arguments, the name of the array and the value to add. This then becomes ${ARRAY_NAME} and ${VARIABLE_VALUE}. Doing the following:

```
set -A $(eval echo \${ARRAY_NAME}) $(eval echo \${${ARRAY_NAME}[*]}) "${VARIABLE_VALUE}"
```

works perfectly in ksh. However,

```
typeset -a $(eval echo \${ARRAY_NAME})=( $(eval echo \${${ARRAY_NAME}[*]}) "${VARIABLE_VALUE}" )
```

does not. This provides

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I know I can just make it a list of strings (e.g. MYARRAY="one two three") and just loop through it using the IFS, but I don't want to lose the ability to use an array either.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: `typeset` makes a variable local to the scope when you use it. That variable will not exist outside that function. Also why `eval`? And using `[*]` instead of quoted `[@]` means your array values can't include spaces (and that shell glob characters will get expanded).

Comment: Looking at http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash to find the syntax of the `typeset -a` I'm not seeing the parens.  On the other hand, looking in the `Arrays` section of that same page it appears that simply `var=(val1 val2 val3)` does work. Haven't used arrays recently in bash so I'm just quoting the manual, but that would be where i would start.

Comment: I've tried it without the eval as well and it doesn't work - for example:

    typeset -a ${ARRAY_NAME}

Comment: Do you need this function at all? Does `ksh` not support `array+=("newvalue")`?

Comment: newer versions of ksh might but I'm hindered by ksh88 on old AIX boxes

Comment: But you have the ksh version working you said, right? So try `eval $ARRAY_NAME+=\(\"\$VARIABLE_VALUE\"\)` in the bash portion?

Comment: holy mother of god that worked. thank you!

Comment: er. how do i mark this answered with your response being the answer ? lol

Comment: Post it as an answer yourself and accept it.  Maybe if @EtanReisner comes back and posts an answer later, delete yours and accept his; but I expect he had a reason to post a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Mostly laziness and a general wariness of answers that involve `eval`. It worked in some quick tests but I wasn't certain that it is robustly safe (though I think it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the assertion that the `ksh` portion of this function is working only the `bash` portion needs to be created. For which the following should work and, I believe, be safe and robust (though evidence to the contrary is welcome).

```
eval $ARRAY_NAME+=\(\"\$VARIABLE_VALUE\"\)
```

First expansion only expands `$ARRAY_NAME` to get

```
eval array+=("$VARIABLE_VALUE")
```

which `eval` then causes to be evaluated again normally.